# Why couldn't I delete files in cmd and PowerShell without `-Force` when I can do that in Explorer?

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-explorer, hidden-file

I copied some files using macOS Finder to an exFAT partition so I ended up having lots of hidden dot files in the folder. I can delete them without any issue in Explorer, but whenever I run the `del` command I always get "Could Not Find" error in cmd even though they can be listed with `dir`

```
D:\>dir /a "D:\._DSCF0035.JPG"
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is 7802-8428

 Directory of D:\

12/04/2021  10:08 SA             4.096 ._DSCF0035.JPG

D:\>del "D:\._DSCF0035.JPG"
Could Not Find D:\._DSCF0035.JPG

D:\>del /f "D:\._DSCF0035.JPG"
Could Not Find D:\._DSCF0035.JPG
```

In PowerShell I also got error if deleting normally but if I add `-Force` to `Remove-Item` it succeeded

```
PS D:\> ls -Force "D:\._DSCF0009.JPG"


    Directory: D:\


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a-h--         4/12/2021  10:08 AM           4096 ._DSCF0009.JPG


PS D:\> rm "D:\._DSCF0009.JPG"
rm : Cannot remove item D:\._DSCF0009.JPG: You do not have sufficient access rights to perform this
operation.
At line:1 char:1
+ rm "D:\._DSCF0009.JPG"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (D:\._DSCF0009.JPG:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
PS D:\> rm -Force "D:\._DSCF0009.JPG" # Succeeded
PS D:\>
```

I tried starting cmd and PowerShell in normal and elevated mode but the same thing happens. Why does it fail in every case except Explorer and PowerShell with `-Force`?

Comment: What version of Windows did this happen on? Example: Windows 10 1903

Comment: @JG7 Windows 10 build 21359

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file has the `h` attribute set; meaning it is hidden. That's why you can't delete when using `del` or `Remove-Item` unless you use the `-Force` parameter. From [Remove-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.1#parameters:%7E:text=Forces%20the%20cmdlet%20to%20remove%20items,or%20read%2Donly%20aliases%20or%20variables.%20The):

> Forces the cmdlet to remove items that cannot otherwise be changed, such as hidden or read-only files or read-only aliases or variables.

Comment: In **Explorer**, the items are only visbie (and thus deletable) wen the "Show Hidden" option is selected. So  "Show Hidden" puts **Explorer** in a persistent `-Force` state for browsing & deletion.

Comment: But why doesn't it work in cmd when I also specify the `/F` option?

Comment: I think as the file is hidden `del /f`  does not work, but `del /a:h` works.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I tried `del /a` and it works

Comment: @phuclv just seen your comment so removed my answer